# What is the difference between has gone and went in this context?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

> A: Is Mr. Bob at home?
>
> B: Sorry, he isn't at home. He_***_***_to Hong Kong for vacation?
>
> A. went
>   B. has gone
>   C. is going

Which one is correct answer? and why it is not the other ones?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may at best be asked on ELL.


Comment: It looks as if someone is just asking for an answer for their homework, not really the purpose of SE, is it ? A little effort and they could have found that [the answer is already on EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50717/is-there-any-difference-between-has-gone-and-went-in-this-context).

Comment: For the record I'd like to say that I voted to migrate it to ELL. (At least I thought I did?)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is B.

If a person is not at home or at work it is because he or she is somewhere else.

> Bill: *Where's Mum? I'm hungry*.
>
> Dad: ***She's gone** shopping, she'll be back soon.*

If a person has returned from a specific location we use the past simple tense, *went*, to express this idea.

> Bill: *Mum where were you? I was really hungry*
>
> Mum: ***I went** shopping, I'm back now so stop moaning.*

The present continuous (and, *be + going to + infinitive verb*) used in: "*I'm going shopping*" or "*He's going to Hong Kong for vacation*" usually expresses a future arrangement or intention.

Comment: went? or went+to? @Mari-Lou A

Comment: Went shopping; went on vacation; went to the shops; went to Hong Kong.

Comment: so I went to shopping is not right?

Comment: No, it isn't. Shopping is not a place, it's an activity. "She went swimming/fishing/dancing" etc. She **went to the** beach/lake/disco etc.

Answer (score 1):

'He has gone to Hong Kong for a vacation'is better. Note the indefinite article before vacation.

You could also say 'He went to HK for a vacation', but it implies the vacation is finished e.g. 'he went last month for a vacation'. If the vacation is still in process I would definitely use 'has gone'.

There are other ways of saying this, such as 'He has gone to HK on vacation', He is on vacation in HK', or 'He is vacationing in Hong Kong', but the last would be less usual, and sounds too grand for most situations.

In Britain we are less inclined to use the word 'vacation'. We tend to go away 'on holiday'. We also 'holiday', using the word as a verb, but to say someone is 'holidaying', is like using 'vacationing'. It can sound excessively pompous, and is sometimes used sarcastically implying 'he ought to be at work'.

Comment: What's the dastardly down vote all about?

Comment: Upvote for teaching me a new word: dastardly :)

Comment: In the US [vacation](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/vacation%5b1%5d) is often uncountable; *When are you taking vacation this year?*

Comment: ‘Is going’ could work, too, in the sense that he is not at home because he is currently on his way to Hong Kong for a vacation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 'Holiday' follows the same sort of rule. Sometimes it is uncountable. e.g. To a work colleague: 'Will you be taking holiday next month'? But mostly it would be 'your holiday', 'a holiday', 'going on holiday' etc.

Comment: Yes, but the lyrics of Cliff Richard's hit song "We're all going on a summer holiday" I can still hear in my mind. Pity me! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, me too. But had it scanned he could equally have sung 'We're all going on holiday' with grammatical correctness. But after introducing the qualifier 'summer' I believe he would have been obliged to use 'a' our 'our'. In fact I have known people sing it as 'our summer holiday'. 'A Voice in the Wilderness' is the one which never allows me to forget one particular teenage party over half a century ago! I wonder why?